# talend etl oracle error 0 row insert

Tags: oracle, talend

I am a newbie to TalendETL and am using Talend Open Studio for Big Data version 6.2.

I have developed a simple Talend ETL job that picks up data from a tFileInputExcel and tOracleInput(dimension date ) and inserts data into my local Oracle Database.

Below is how my package looks :

[image]

[image]

this job run but i get 0 rows insert into my local Oracle Database

Comment: How are you tMap settings and your tOracleOutput settings?

Comment: tMap_3 join conditions should be checked as its clear  you are not getting any output from tMap_3

Comment: having the same problem after 6 years, did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your picture shows that no rows come out your tMap Component. Verify that your links inside the Tmap are corrects.

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is no data that matches between fgf.LIBELLE_MOIS and row2.B.

Comment: in file input excel i have 15 row of column of every month but in dim_dat i have 30 row for every month.