# talend etl tmap join tfileInputExcel and Date dimension error

Tags: etl, talend

I created a job containing *tMap* join `date dimension`:

- id date
- date_du_jour
- libelle_mois
- ..

and `tFileInputExcel`:

- id
- mois
- ..

to load a fact table but i get an error:

```
0 row input in my fact table.
```

Below is how my package looks:
[image]
[image]

I need your proposition.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Right now you select data out of the date dimension, join some data out of the excel and you aren't using the join data but instead use one field out of the date dimension which seems to be empty. How does the data look like? Are those fields joinable?

Comment: i want to load my fact table then .

Comment: i want to load my fact table which represente my data marts.i use just id date in my fact table but i join libelle mois in date dimension ( with mois in file excel( i have 12 month )  .

Comment: I really don't understand what you are trying to do. Why is there an Excel file *and* a database input? How does the data look like?

Comment: See [this link](http://diethardsteiner.blogspot.de/2012/02/talend-open-studio-populating-date.html) in how to create date dimensions in Talend without database or Excel inputs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [talend etl oracle error 0 row insert](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39042862/talend-etl-oracle-error-0-row-insert)